# How to display the comments of columns on Zeppelin?

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, apache-zeppelin

I'm working on Zeppelin and I want to see the describe of some tables in my databases but I can't see the comments of the columns, I used %sql and %livy.sql interpreter if that could help you for answering.

On the other side when I use Hive, I can see the comment of columns when I make the same request: describe table_name.

Have you ever encountered this type of problem? is this due to Zeppelin's setting?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me. You can try this too :)

```
%livy.spark
val hive_context = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
hive_context.sql("desc your_db_name.your_table_name").show()
```

I can see the column name,data type and also the comment of columns as seen in hive :)